# Hide overflowed text inside css3 column in <ul>

Tags: css

My Code

**Css**

```
 .newspaper {
   -webkit-columns: 100px 12;
   /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-columns: 100px 12;
   /* Firefox */
   columns: 100px 12;
   list-style-type: none;
   /*font-size : 8px;*/
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="newspaper">
  <li title="Number fdgfsfsfdsfsdfsdfsdf">1.&nbsp;Number fdgfsfsfdsfsdfsdfsdf</li>
  <li>2.&nbsp; number</li>
  <li>3.&nbsp; number</li>
  <li>4.&nbsp; number</li>
  <li>5.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>6.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>7.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>8.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>9.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>10.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>11.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>12.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>13.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>14.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>15.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>16.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>17.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>18.&nbsp; number </li>
  <li>19.&nbsp; number </li>
</ul>
```

My view 
[image]

I wanna to  hide overflowed text in the column.

like

```
1. Number fd // gfsfsfdsfsd par will be hidden
```

How can i do that ?? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this css

**css**

```
li{
   width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```